# While my app is running, how can I update the current activity with the contents a GCM notification, without clicking on the notification?

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Is this possible? Currently when I receive a notification `OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)` fires, but I'm not able to reference any of my `Activities` in this context. Is there any way for me to do this? Or do I need the user to click the notification to update the activity and view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OnMessage handler, just execute:

```
 var i = new Intent(this, typeof(MyActivity));
 i.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
 context.StartActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You can send a `LocalBroadcast` inside `onMessage`. See [LocalBroadcast Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html).:

> LocalBroadcast Manager is a helper to register for and send broadcasts of Intents to local objects within your process. The data you are broadcasting won't leave your app, so don't need to worry about leaking private data.`

You can send the LocalBroadcast from within the `omMessage`. Then inside you `Activity` you can listen to the broadcast which can be with an Intent message. Whenever you receive that local broadcast, you may do the desired action.

See [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager) on how to implement it. Hope it helps you.